# Borel-Stieltjes measure problem with floor functions.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We have 2 functions,

$$\alpha(x)=\left\{ \begin{array} {cl} \lfloor x \rfloor + \log(1+x),& x\geq 0 \\  \lfloor x  \rfloor, & x<0  \end{array} \right.$$

$$\beta(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor$$

and $\mu_\alpha,\mu_\beta$ their Borel-Stieltjes measures.

1. *First I have to prove that for every Borel $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ we have $\mu_\beta=\mathrm{card}(A\cap \mathbb{Z})$*

I did it by separing $A$ in intervals of the type $(a_i,b_i]$ and so $$\mu_\beta(A)=\sum (\lfloor b_i \rfloor-\lfloor a_i \rfloor)=\sum \mathrm{card}((a_i,b_i]\cap\mathbb{Z})=\mathrm{card}(A\cap\mathbb{Z})$$

Do you think is that right?

2. *Then I have to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ that satisfies 
   $$\mu_\alpha-\mu_\beta=\int_A f dm$$ where m is Lebesgue measure*

I found that

$$(\mu_\alpha-\mu_\beta)((a,b])=\left\{ \begin{array} {cl} 0,& b,a< 0 \\  \log(b+1), & a<0,b\geq 0 \\   \log(b+1)-\log(a+1), & a,b\geq 0 \end{array} \right.$$
but I don't know exactly how to use it.

3. *Finally I have to calculate $\mu_\alpha([1,3]\setminus \mathbb{Q})$ and $\mu_\alpha(C) $ where $C$ is the Cantor set.*

I'm wondering if maybe exercise 2 can be used... because this time I cannot used intervals, I think.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You proved it for finite union of half open intervals. Now you have to extend this to the Borel sets. This can be done by a monotone class argument.
2. You have the data $g(a,b):=\int_{(a,b)}f\mathrm dm$ for $a\lt b$, and you want to deduce from this the value of $f$. Since $g(a,b)=0$ for $a\lt b\lt 0$, we have $f(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0$.  To determine the value for $x\gt 0$, use $h(b)-h(a)=\int_a^b h'(t)\mathrm dt$ where $h(t)= \log(1+t)$.
3. Yes, you can use question 2.: if you know $\mu_\beta(B)$ for some Borel set $B$, then you can deduce $\mu_\alpha(B)$. The former is easier to compute.

Comment: Sets of the last question are borel sets?

Comment: Yes: for the first one, write it as the intersection of Borel sets. For the Cantor set, it is more involved, but if you know a definition of the Cantor set as an intersection of some closed sets (or if you know its closeness), you are done.